# How to tie instances of three classes together?

Tags: java

I have a customer class.

```
public Customer(boolean regular, boolean payAhead, boolean loyal, String userName, double amountOfStorage) {
    this.regular = regular;
    this.payAhead = payAhead;
    this.loyal = loyal;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.amtOfStore = amountOfStorage;
}
```

Im using a Map for the user to choose what customer they are through a JTextField.

```
Map<String, Customer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Kyle", new Customer(true, false, false, "Kyle", 1000.00));
map.put("Andrew", new Customer(false, true, false, "Andrew", 0.00));
map.put("Connor", new Customer(false, false, true, "Connor", 5000.00));
```

This all works. I also have a Store class.

```
public Store(String name, double cost, double mbAmount, int itemCnt, double ship) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.mbAmount = mbAmount;
    this.itemCnt = itemCnt;
    this.ship = ship;
}
```

With multiple Store instances.

```
Store sitem1 = new Store("Movie", 20.00, 500, 0, 0.00);
Store sitem2 = new Store("Lamborghini", 2000000.00, 0, 0, 5000);
Store sitem3 = new Store("Song", .99, 50, 0, 0);
Store sitem4 = new Store("Headphones", 25.00, 0, 0, 3.00);
Store sitem5 = new Store("iPhone", 894.92, 0, 0, 10.00);
Store sitem6 = new Store("Coffe Maker", 50.67, 0, 0, 7.00);
Store sitem7 = new Store("Video Game", 59.99, 40000, 0, 0);
Store sitem8 = new Store("Laptop", 500.00, 0, 0, 6.76);
Store sitem9 = new Store("Old Movie", 2.99, 100, 0, 0);
Store sitem10 = new Store("Tv Show", .99, 20, 0, 0);
```

and a ShoppingCart Class.

```
    public ShoppingCart(double shippingCost, double storageSize, double totalPrice, double temp, int cartCount) {
    this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
    this.storageSize = storageSize;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    this.temp = temp;
    this.cartCount = cartCount;
}
```

I need it so when one customer logs off(Program never closes) and another logs on the Store and Shopping Cart class are unique to him, while keeping the information that was entered by the previous customer. Once again teh program never closes in this scenario.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You need a list of Store objects somewhere. You also need a ShoppingCart associated with a Customer. You may find that a database would be useful here. Sqlite is a good starting point

Comment: are you running this code in a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ShoppingCart to your Customer class, representing that customer's current shopping cart.

Access and modify shopping cart through the Customer.

> A customer **has a** shopping cart.

Comment: This doesn't really address how to save "the session" of a cart

Comment: I'm suspecting he is not there yet (the persistence part), and just holding everything in memory.

Comment: Probably not, but it was part of the question. "log off... while keeping the information that was entered by the previous customer."

Comment: This worked. Added store and shopping cart to customer. Thank you.